# Haskell polymorphic deconstruction

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

I'm started working with [Juicy Pixels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels) library and have some problem with deconstructing.

There are type:

```hs
data DynamicImage =
    ImageY8   (Image Pixel8)
    | ImageYA8  (Image PixelYA8)
    | ImageRGB8 (Image PixelRGB8)
    | ImageRGBA8 (Image PixelRGBA8) 
    | ImageYCbCr8 (Image PixelYCbCr8)
```

where Pixel* is instances of **Pixel a** class

There are some functions that work with **Image a** type and i wish to extract **Image a** from **DynamicImage**, but i can't

When i try to do something like

```hs
img :: (Pixel a) => DynamicImage -> Image a
img (ImageY8 i) = i
img (ImageYA8 i) = i  
img (ImageRGB8 i) = i
img (ImageRGBA8 i) = i  
img (ImageYCbCr8 i) = i
```

interpreter thwors an errors like

```hs
Couldn't match type `PixelYCbCr8' with `GHC.Word.Word8'
Expected type: Image b
  Actual type: Image Pixel8
In the expression: i
In an equation for `img': img (ImageY8 i) = i
```

Is there any other way to extract **Image a** data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach does not work because the type signature of `img` promises to provide an Image for *every* `a`, not just one particular chosen by `img` itself.

One possibility is to change the type signature to also take the function that will handle the polymorphic image, and use `RankNTypes` to allow that:

```
withImg :: DynamicImage -> (forall a. Pixel a => Image a -> b) -> b
withImg (ImageY8 i) f = f i
withImg (ImageYA8 i) f = f i  
withImg (ImageRGB8 i) f = f i
withImg (ImageRGBA8 i) f = f i  
withImg (ImageYCbCr8 i) f = f i
```

This ensures that the function passed to `withImg` will accept any `Image` as an argument, without any further information about it.

Comment: This is actually a transformation of `exists a. Pixel a =>  DynamicImage -> Image a` into continuation-passing style.

Comment: True, but that is not a valid Haskell type. Is there a non-continuation-passing-style variant that works in Haskell?

Comment: `data SomeImage = forall a. Pixel a => SomeImage (Image a)` (which needs `-XExistentialQuantification`).

Comment: Also, it's transformation of **(a)** `DynamicImage -> (exists a. Pixel a => Image a)` - note the position of `exists`. **(b)** `exists a. Pixel a => DynamicImage -> Image a` is a bit stronger in the sense that you can go from **b** to **a**, but not the other way around.

Comment: Ok, you can introduce a new type. But to actually use the functions mentioned in the original question, which take a "Pixel a" and not a SomeImage, you’d again have to do a CPS transformation.